# Text component react-native - how to escape newline but allow /n to display by escaping it as //n

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a Text react-native component to make a label for my app. I would like to be able to turn all `\n` into an actual line break but be able to display `\n` in my Text component if I escape it like this: `\\n`

I've tried many things but I can't seem to get it to work, including replace, replaceAll, with attempted escape configurations
current code snippet:

```
const textCustomSetter = (newValue, newComponent) => {
    newComponent.properties.Text = newValue;
    newComponent.properties.children = newValue.split('\\n').join('\n');
};
```

where textCustomSetter is a design and runtime setter property of my Text component.

This correctly captures `\n` and turns it into line break, but turns `\\n` into `\` followed by a line break.

Answer (score 3):

Just `replace` that with a regex:

```
newValue.replace(/[^\\]\\n/g, "\n");
```

This works by *not* matching a single backslash, then matching a literal `\n` (as in, a backslash and an `n`, not a newline character), and replacing it with a newline.

Comment: Apologies but how would I capture '\\n' to turn it into '\n' ?                                                                                           
prev:                                                                            
     newComponent.properties.children = newValue.split('\\n').join('\n');                                                                                              now:                                         
     newComponent.properties.Text = newValue;         
     newComponent.properties.children = newValue.replace(/[^\\]\\n/g, "\n");

Comment: So what do you want @LaCoder? Capture `\\n`, then turn it into a newline, or the *literal* `\n`?

Comment: Essentially I'd like to write a js function that has a regex where \n makes a newline, \\n displays a literal \n, \\\n displays \\n, so the case would be that if you type \n it makes a newline, if you type two or more \\ before the n, it displays one less \ before the n. \\\n -> \\n \\\\n -> \\\n So I know newValue.search(/[^\\]\\n/g matches \n and newValue.search(/[\\]\\n/g) matches two or more slashes before the n. But how can I parse the string to apply my rules. If you have any guidance to point me to, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Actually this (search(/[\]\\n/g) matches two or more slashes before the n) doesn't work, still need to figure that out

Comment: var reg = new RegExp(/\\{2,}n/g); This matches two or more slashes followed by an n. My question is, how can I take the string ab\ncd\\nef\\\ng and render it as ab ↵ cd \n ef \\ng

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out. This turns \n into newlines and reduces all strings of 2 or more slashes followed by an n to one less slash. I know this is a very specific spec but thought I'd share how I got it to work. Thanks for your help getting me unstuck on the regex!

Now I just have to figure out the syntax to get this working on the front end.

```
const textCustomSetter = (newValue, newComponent) => {
    newComponent.properties.Text = newValue;
    //split on one or more slashes before an n, keep the delimiter
    var arr = newValue.split(/(\\{1,}n)/g);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == "\\n") {
      //address the newline
        arr[i] = "\n";
      }
      //everything else, gets one slash reduced 
      if (arr[i].match(/\\{2,}n/g)){
        arr[i] = arr[i].substr(1);
      }
    }
    newComponent.properties.children = arr;
};
```